# Swift - boundingBox cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm using SceneKit to show a text node. Here is my code:

```
// foo.swift
extension SCNNode {
    func getNodeSize() -> (width: Float, height: Float) {
        let (min, max) = boundingBox
        return (width: max.x - min.x, height: max.y - min.y)
    }

    func setPivotCenter() {
        let (min, max) = boundingBox
        let x = min.x + 0.5 * (max.x - min.x)
        let y = min.y + 0.5 * (max.y - min.y)
        let z = min.z + 0.5 * (max.z - min.z)
        self.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(x, y, z)
    }
}

// bar.swift
func foo() {
    let textGeometry = SCNText(string: "foo", extrusionDepth: 0.01)
    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: textGeometry)

    // set pivot
    textNode.setPivotCenter()

    // get size
    let (width, height) = textNode.getNodeSize()

    // some other codes
}
```

But it **sometimes(contingency)** crashed in getNodeSize() function:

```
symbol stub for: (extension in SceneKit):__C.SCNBoundingVolume.boundingBox.getter : (min: __C.SCNVector3, max: __C.SCNVector3)

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xxx)

or

malloc: *** error for object 0x283811360: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

I change the two extension function code into one then everything seems OK:

```
// bar.swift
func foo() {
    let textGeometry = SCNText(string: "foo", extrusionDepth: 0.01)
    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: textGeometry)
    let (min, max) = textNode.boundingBox

    // set pivot
    let x = min.x + 0.5 * (max.x - min.x)
    let y = min.y + 0.5 * (max.y - min.y)
    let z = min.z + 0.5 * (max.z - min.z)
    textNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(dx, dy, dz)

    // get size
    let (width, height) = (width: max.x - min.x, height: max.y - min.y)

    // some other codes
}
```

My environment:

macOS: 10.14 Beta (18A293u)

Xcode: 10.0 beta (10L176w)

Swift: 4.2

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I have a very similar issue on iOS 12 and Xcode 10. Did you learn something new?

Comment: @DamianDudycz Unfortunately

Comment: Your post helped me anyway, because as you pointed this only happens if you access this variable in different scope, then it is created. So I subclassed SCNText, added a variable of the same type as boundingBox, and when I create and configure text I store it value in this variable. Then I can read it from this new var. But this is just for some cases - I am not changing this SCNText anywhere after it was created. So thanks for pointing out about not crashing when using it in the same function, this helped me.

Comment: @DamianDudycz  You're welcome.